# The quickest and most efficient way to split string in PHP

Tags: php, string

I need to split string by just finding the first character. What is the quickest way to write it?

**An example of string:**

```
$string = 'Some text here| some text there--and here|another text here';
```

**Expected result:**

```
$new_string = 'Some text here';
```

This is a solution, I have. Is there a more efficient way to do it?

```
$explode = explode('|', $string);  
$new_string = explode[0];
```

Comment: How many strings you need to split at once?

Comment: one, but doesnt matter does it?

Comment: Indeed, it doesn't matter, which way you choose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `strpos()` and `substr()`. `Strpos()` will return as soon as the first occurrence is found, while `explode()` has to walk the whole string.

Answer (score 3):

Use `strstr()`:

```
strstr($string, "|", true);
```

Will return everything until the first pipe (|).

Comment: just to say, 3rd parameter was added in php 5.3

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = 'Some text here| some text there--and here|another text here';
$string = substr($string, 0, strpos($string,'|'));
print $string;
```

Edit: Using strstr() is better.

Comment: This just adds clutter as compared to other methods.

Comment: I have used this solution you mentioned above, strstr was not good enough for me and it cut wrong part

Answer (score 1):

explode can be turned into one-liner with

```
list($first,) = explode('|', $string,2);
```

however, strtok looks like most concise solution.

As for the efficiency - it doesn't matter at all, which way to choose to perform such a negligible operation.

Whatever inefficiency is coming from the **amount** of processed data. And sane programmer would avoid processing large amounts of data at any cost. While whatever else matters are complete rubbish from the efficiency point of view.

Answer (score 0):

best would be go with:

```
$first = strtok($string, '|');
```

you can go and with explode if you like it:

```
$explode = explode('|', $string, 1);
```

also `strpos()`, `substr()` and `strstr()` is good for this.